# Neo4j browser query deeplink possible?

Tags: graph, neo4j, neo4j-browser

I would like to link the Neo4j Browser with certain queries which should show the result graph automatically when clicking the link. Does anyone know whether there is a possibility to deeplink the Neo4j browser with a cypher query so that it executes this automatically? I already checked for `../browser/?cmd=play&arg=xyz` synthax which goes towards the direction but does not execute cypher. Also a POST call would be fine. I know there's the REST API which allows me the execution of queries but does not visualize.

thanks for your support,

Jens

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible.

Imagine that you find on internet a hidden link with this command : `MATCH (n) DETACH DELETE n`.

Do you want that query to be automatically executed ? I'm sure not !

I don't know what you want to achieve with that, but if you just want to display a graph on a web page, try to develop something with `sigma.js`, `viz.js`, `cytoscape` or `d3` ...

You will a lot of help on internet for this.